# Fusion Tables: Polygon not displayed as of certain zoom level

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables, polygons

I'm working on a map that shows different population statistics on a rather granular level in Berlin (447 sub-districts).

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1tIAPGaYK1iEWWLANQOupkAqCcPhVauMjdPS1qOs#map:id=3

For some reason, a small number of polygons (3) is not displayed as soon as you zoom into the map (12 or higher).

As the polygons are displayed at the level before, they should have the proper coordinates. I first thought the shapefiles (kmls provided by the local statistics authority) might be buggy, but that does not seem to be the case.

Can anybody explain to me why this happens?

Thank you very much!

Michael

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities that I can think of:

1. it is a complexity problem or a winding direction issue with the polygon. [Thread on Fusion Tables Users Group discussing this issue](https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/browse_frm/thread/9e37c4238fd7346/9857a1ac5fc7b426?lnk=gst&q=polygon++complexity#9857a1ac5fc7b426).
2. it is a complexity issue with the number of "features" on the tile. [See Limits in the documentation, it used to be more clearly defined](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables).

Reversing the winding direction of two of the problem polygons seems to fix the issue:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S787935DQC4

Comment: If you still have your original table content around, you probably should report this as an issue on the [Fusion Tables issue list](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/list).

Comment: Hi geocodezip,

thank you very much!

It doesn't seem to be one of the "Limits", as all the numbers in the sheet is far less than given in the documentation.

And knowing the workaround is really good.